# Mock Open API endpoints that haven‘t been implemented yet?

Tags: api, mocking, openapi, mockserver, oas

Mocking endpoints an Open API Specification file defines isn't all that difficult.

However I am trying to mock **only** the endpoints that don't have an implementation yet.

For example I have an OAS file that defines an `GET /dogs` and an `GET /cats` endpoint.
Now when I implement `GET /dogs` in a - for example - Nest.js application and that application is running, I would want to have a mock server that only mocks the `GET /cats` endpoint.

That would make it possible to bundle the mock server and the application and to deploy them together, so that some form of response (either the implementation or the mocked) is always returned for every endpoint.

Is there some sort of tool/mock-server that has this kind of ability? Would doing something like that even make sense?